# Changing the color of a listview view item that notifies data changes through an outer click listener of another list view

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to change the color of the first row in "monitoredpatientlsit" which is a list view. The change should happen if I click on an item in allpatientslist and it already exists in monitoredpatient. So suppose I click on item 3, which also happens to be item 3 in monitoredpatients. I expect the code to change the color of the first view in monitored patient to red. However it doesn't, and I think it has to something to do with "notifydatasetchanged" method, because when I comment it out, it would work the way I want it to, but when I put it back to the code, there are no changes in the color at all. Any Idea why?

```
      allpatientslist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (selectedpatients.contains(allpatients.get(position))){
                selectedpatients.remove(selectedpatients.indexOf(allpatients.get(position)));
                refomatToRed();
                monitoredPatientListAdapator.notifyDataSetChanged();
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F4F6F1"));

            }else{
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B0D880"));
                selectedpatients.add(allpatients.get(position));
                monitoredPatientListAdapator.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    });

public void refomatToRed(){
    monitoredpatientslist.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        }
```

Edit: 
I fixed it by just implementing the change of color inside the adaptor, since every time an item is removed by view due to the scrolling feature, the item is actually destroyed and will lose any formatting down to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter, the list is re-drawn. Changing the color of the first child has no effect because this child is destroyed at the following line.
Try inverting the lines like this:

```
monitoredPatientListAdapator.notifyDataSetChanged();
refomatToRed();
```